# outputdebugstring exception on windows10

Tags: winapi, windows-10

I update my computer to Windows10.

It cause an exception in `OutputDebugString` callstack i guess.

When i called `OutputDebugString`, the callstack was shown like this.

```
ntdll.dll!_WerpWaitForCrashReporting@16()
ntdll.dll!_RtlReportExceptionHelper@16()
ntdll.dll!_RtlReportException@12()
ntdll.dll!_RtlpReportInvalidExceptionChain@8()
ntdll.dll!RtlDispatchException()
ntdll.dll!_KiUserExceptionDispatcher@8()
KernelBase.dll!_RaiseException@16()
KernelBase.dll!OutputDebugStringW()
```

It looks like windows error report process.

Why dose this happen?

Is `OutputDebugString` deprecated in Windows10?

Thanks.

Comment: Even if it's deprecated, it doesn't mean that it will crash your machine on calling that function. So, IMHO, the problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: To check whether an API is deprecated or not, kindly visit the msdn for the same. In this case, you can go to - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363362(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks for your kind advices. I will try to find the cause.

Comment: call `RtlpReportInvalidExceptionChain` say that your *SEH* exception chain is corrupt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does this happen?

There is an error in your code somewhere. Perhaps a heap corruption, or an invalid argument passed to the function. For. Instance it may be that the string is not null terminated, or that the memory you passed has already been freed.

If I had to bet, I would expect that this final explanation is the most likely.

> Is `OutputDebugString` deprecated in Windows10?

No. Much as you might be inclined to think the problem is related to the OS upgrade, it is an issue with your code. The upgrade has just happened to highlight the problem with your code, a problem that has always existed but only now happens to manifest.

Answer (score 1):

OutputDebugString *works by* generating an exception. The debugger catches it as a debug event ("1st chance"), then extracts the string argument and displays it.

The important part in the stack you show is `_RtlpReportInvalidExceptionChain`. What this means is that somehow your try/catch chain was corrupted. Perhaps a mismatch in exception handling model (/EHsc) or otherwise.